# Guess the word - It can be found in a map

Tags: word

<sub>Overall edit</sub>

Following the *hot trends* over the stack network, I couldn't resist on making my own puzzle.

--> That would suppose to mean that I had seen a puzzle here yesterday (or pre-yesterday) that was seeking for a word of the same nature as of mine's.

> The word I am looking for exists and can be found in a map!!!

Bellow I will provide clues for the two halves of the word (that means that the 1st part has the same length with the 2nd).

> The 1st half:
>
> 1. gets *kicked* (but that's not its primary use. It could be kicked
>      after usage). This half is going *places*.
> 2. getting inspired by this, some people and their work/product/*art*
>      got really famous.

<sub>It might even get "posthumous fame", well
    not as much as the Greek Alexander the Great, but who knows
    now? It's too *soon* to say.</sub>

> The 2nd half:
>
> 1. was created around 1980 and was a replacement to many others of its
>      kind, after *printing* `Hello world`.
> 2. was a *name* of an English woman, which was somehow related to the
>      concept of the former list item.

Which word do I have in mind?

Comment: If I felt like getting slapped I would say the answer is "ballhog" in front of a female acquaintance.

Comment: @Goinghamateur I didn't even know the existence of that word, but a search resulted in lots of memes. :))) I did edit the question, giving more clues...

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Glad you were inspired - it's always great to have more puzzle creators around here c:

Comment: Thank you @Deusovi. Well that;s (one more) proof that you are doing a great job here. Note that the "inspired" part in my question **is also a clue**, which ideally should reveal the nature of the word we are seeking! In case you upvoted, thanks! :)

Comment: You say "a female". Does that mean it is a particular woman you have in mind or all women generally?

Comment: @gsamaras, did this word already exist and you're separating the word, or has it become an accepted word based on the two parts you're describing?

Comment: @Areeb one woman. John it exists, I updated my post!

Comment: @gsamaras, cool. That's a good puzzle, I was just wondering if you were looking for a word that had been formed from those words, like 'emoticon' or something.

Comment: I've changed the title to describe the puzzle a bit more. Fell free to remove/change back if you don't like it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Canada** (as a country, it's likely to be found on a map)

The 1st half:

> **Can**: 1. There's the game [Kick the can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kick_the_can). 2. The "*art*" might be refering to Andy Warhol's *[Campbell's Soup Cans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campbell%27s_Soup_Cans)*

The 2nd half:

> **Ada**: 1. Refers to the [Ada programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language)), which first appeared in 1980. Printing `Hello world` refers to a classic example of [a simple computer program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) which just prints `Hello world`. 2. The Ada language was named after [Ada Lovelace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace), an English mathematician who is credited with being the first computer programmer.

Comment: Well, my question surely brought another new user on this site! :) Hope you liked my puzzle.... :)

Comment: @gsamaras was that the right answer?

Comment: @gsamaras I did. It's the first one I could actually solve, though (that wasn't already solved, and without taking me a *lot* of time, at least). Well, I *think* I solved it...

Comment: Yeap, I just waited to see his explanation to accept it. What I had in mind for the 1st half is: **kicking your can all over the place**!!! This lyric has been pinned down to my mind from when we hear it on an English course at school (as a listening exercise).

Comment: @gsamaras I'm so mad at myself! I was looking at another puzzle and was staring at the answer for so long!!

Comment: Oh I see @Areeb, but at least now you are sure about the answer. So interesting that Rodrigo was able to find the answer without following my thought on the 1st part... ;)

Answer (score 10):

Are you thinking of -

> ballet

The first part -

> A ball is kicked. Also hosting a ball (party) could make someone popular.

The second part -

> ET the Extra-Terrestrial came out in 1982. Also, ET sounds like the suffix "ette" which is applied to some feminine nouns (e.g. "dude" versus "dudette").

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, and good answer!

Comment: I agree with @Deusovi, good answer! Also I didn't even know that the last word you are mentioning existed!! However, **no, this is not the answer**! Maybe I should provide more clues to solve the mystery, but not yet... ;)

Comment: dudette is 90's slang :)